# How to delete user when user profile is being deleted

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

How to tell the `Django` to `delete` user when user profile is being `deleted`?

I have created a `user` profile to extend `user`. Now, I want to set `Django` to delete `user` when `user profile` is deleted and vice versa.

Is it possible?

**models.py:**

```
class UserTranslatorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)

class UserCustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Comment: This isn't enough code.

Comment: So, what should I paste here?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this would be to override the **def delete** function in the profile model. As you might have guessed the function will be called once  a profile instance is deleted.